# Reading HTML with session from httpcomponents

Tags: java, html, session, apache-httpcomponents

How would I go on using the logged-in session that I attained through use of Apache's httpcomponents to utilize html (code-wise) on a site that requires you to be logged in?

This is what it looks like when I use httpcomponents:

```
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://whatever.com/login.php");

    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "whatever")); //set your own username
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "whatever")); //set your own password

    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I assume that the answer to my problem lies somewhere with the HttpEntity class, but I feel like I am stuck..

To clarify: After I've logged in as shown above, I would need to access a page, with the session from above, that requires you to be logged in (e.g. membersonly.php or whatever), and then read and use the content from this page in Java.

Hope I made myself clear enough :) Looking forward to any answer.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, HTTP sessions are tracked through [cookies](http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/session-cookies-used-for.html) received from the server which must be sent in the subsequent requests.

Just follow this [example](http://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/QuickStart) which performs form-based login.